# Issue with string.replaceAll

Tags: java

I'm just trying to replace a string `\\`  with `\\\\`

Below is the program but it is terminating

```
String path="\\dctmadmin\\Human Resource\\Training\\Procedures\\Formalities\\Legalities\\Material";         

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
// replace this string \\ with \\\\
String formatedPath = path.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
System.out.println(" string after formatting using replaceAll = "+formatedPath);
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(" time take in milli seconds for String.replaceAll = "+Long.toString(end-start) );
```

Please let me know the mistake i was doing.

Comment: Terminating? Do you get any errors?

Comment: `Long.toString(end-start)` is not neccessary. `(end-start)` will suffice.

Comment: Its giving Thread[main] (suspended Exception PatternSyntaxException)

Comment: Since you don't require any regex functionality, think about using String.replace(String, String) instead of String.replaceAll(String, String)

Comment: In your String, all \\ are really one \ inside the String. Your replaceAll gives a String with two real \\, so it´s OK. Test doing System.out.println("\\dctmadmin\\Human Resource\\Training\\Procedures\\Formalities\\Legalities\\Material") and System.out.println("\\drt...\\Material".replaceAll(...))

Comment: yeh..i restarted eclipse and now it's working but displaying same \\ without replacing with \\\\

Comment: @Chuidiang This is a Java regex to match one backslash: `"\\\\"`

Comment: after placing string.replace also its stil displaying only \\

Comment: @Sukumar What is your expected output? Like this? `\\\\dctmadmin\\\\Human Resource\\\\Training\\\\Procedures\\\\Formalities\\\\Legalities\\\\Material`

Comment: it does what it should! Try `System.out.println(path);` and then `System.out.println(formatedPath);`

Comment: hmm.yeh you are correct. Its escaping one \ . just wondering whether we can get the output as \\\\dctmadmin\\\\Human Resource\\\\Training\\\\Procedures\\\\Formalities\\\\Legalities\\\\Material

Comment: Your code working fine for me.

Comment: thanks everyone..now i understood that \\ in java means only one escape \  and to get my expected output i did path.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"); and it started giving output as \\\\dctmadmin\\\\Human Resource\\\\Training\\\\Procedures\\\\Formalities\\\\Legalities\\\\Material

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a literal string replacement where you don't need the power of regular expressions you should use `replace` rather than `replaceAll` as it's simpler and more efficient.

```
// replace single backslash with double
String formatedPath = path.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

Comment: Yes. It works but is it possible to display output as \\\\dctmadmin\\\\Human Resource\\\\Training\\\\Procedures\\\\Formalities\\\\Legalities\\\\Material

Comment: as per Polppan suggestion i changed it to   String formatedPath = path.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\");
 and then its displaying \\\\dctmadmin\\\\Human Resource\\\\Training\\\\Procedures\\\\Formalities\\\\Legalities\\\\Material

Answer (score 1):

Your real String contains only one \. Test

```
System.out.println("\\dctmadmin\\Human Resource\\Training\\Procedures\\Formalities\\Legalities\\Material");
```

So your replaceAll is running OK if it returns double \\ when System.out.println("your string".replaceAll(...));

Answer (score 1):

Try as

```
String path = 
    "\\dctmadmin\\Human Resource\\Training\\Procedures\\Formalities\\Legalities\\Material";


long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
// replace this string \\ with \\\\

String formatedPath = path.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\");

System.out.println(" string after formatting using replaceAll = " + 
                   formatedPath);


long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println(" time take in milli seconds for String.replaceAll = " + Long.toString(end - start));

System.out.println(" path  "+formatedPath);
```

Comment: Your cde works and displays output as   \\\\dctmadmin\\\\Human Resource\\\\Training\\\\Procedures\\\\Formalities\\\\Legalities\\\\Material

Answer (score 0):

in  your string when you say \ it actually means \ escaped by another \, thus it is replacing it correctly.

```
String path="\\dctmadmin\\Human Resource\\Training\\Procedures\\Formalities\\Legalities\\Material";

         System.out.println("String before: "+ path);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // replace this string \\ with \\\\

          String formatedPath = path.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");

          System.out.println(" string after formatting using replaceAll = "+formatedPath);
```

output i got

```
   String before:  \dctmadmin\Human Resource\Training\Procedures\Formalities\Legalities\Material

     string after formatting using replaceAll = \\dctmadmin\\Human Resource\\Training\\Procedures\\Formalities\\Legalities\\Material
     time take in milli seconds for String.replaceAll = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You did right.
In Java string `\\` represents one backslash, in regex it is the non-String escape.

```
    String formatedPath = path.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
    System.out.println("path         = " + path);
    System.out.println("formatedPath = " + formatedPath);
```

gives

```
path         = \dctmadmin\Human Resource\Training\Pr...s\Form...s\L...s\Material
formatedPath = \\dctmadmin\\Human Resource\\Training\\Pr..s\\Form...s\\Material
```

Answer (score 0):

Output of

```
string after formatting using replaceAll = \\dctmadmin\\Human Resource\\Training\\Procedures\\Formalities\\Legalities\\Material
```

is correct. It looks like it hasn't changed because you're discounting the fact that the '\' in your original are escaped :)